# Symfony2 cascasing dropdown value change via ajax not accepting on submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have two entity dropdowns field in my symfony form. On the front end i change the option list of 2nd drop drown using ajax based on the value of first dropdown selected value. and Upon submitting the form i get the error that,

```
This value is not valid.
```

below is the code;

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="State")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="province_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $Province;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="District")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="district_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $District;
```

and in the form,

```
 ->add('domicileDistrict','entity', [
                'label' => ucwords('District'),
                'class'=>'GeneralBundle\Entity\District',
                'required' => true,
                'mapped' => true,
                'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control'],
                'label_attr' => ['class' => 'control-label'],
            ])
->add('domicileProvince','entity', [
                'label' => ucwords('Province'),
                'class'=>'GeneralBundle\Entity\State',
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control select2'],
                'label_attr' => ['class' => 'control-label'],
            ])
```

and on front end,

```
 $("#profile_from_type_domicileProvince").change(function() {
                var state = $('option:selected', this).val();
                getDistrictByState(state);
            });

            function getDistrictByState(state){
                var dict = {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{{ url('ajax_district_by_stateId') }}?id=" + state,
                    success: function(e) {
                       $("#profile_from_type_domicileDistrict option").remove();
                        $.each(e, function(e, p) {
                            $("#profile_from_type_domicileDistrict").append($("<option />", {
                                value: e,
                                text: p
                            }));
                        });
                    } 
                };
                $.ajax(dict);
            }
```

UPDATE: Add PRE_SUBMIT Event;

After suggestion form @Alsatian, I update my form and add the event as below, but nothing happens on selecting first dropdown.

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, [$this, 'preSubmitData']);

  public function preSubmitData(FormEvent $event){
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        if (array_key_exists('Province', $data)) {
            $state = $data['Province'];
            $event->getForm()
                ->add('District','entity', [
                    'label' => ucwords('District'),
                    'class'=>'GeneralBundle\Entity\District',
                    'required' => true,
                    'mapped' => true,
                    'query_builder' => function(DistrictRepository $repository) use ($state) {
                        $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('d')
                            ->andWhere('d.verified = :verified')
                            ->andWhere('d.active = :active')
                            ->setParameter('verified', true)
                            ->setParameter('active', true);

                        if ($state instanceof State) {
                            $qb = $qb->where('d.state = :state')
                                ->setParameter('state', $state);
                        } elseif (is_numeric($state)) {
                            $qb = $qb->where('d.state = :state')
                                ->setParameter('state', $state);
                        } else {
                            $qb = $qb->where('d.state = 1');
                        }

                        return $qb;
                    },
                    'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control select2'],
                    'label_attr' => ['class' => 'control-label'],
                ]);

        }
    }
```

Comment: `PRE_SUBMIT` does nothing on change of first select box as your are asking. when form submitted, It will populate required options to dynamic select box. Do you still get `This value is not valid.` error on submission?

Comment: @Jeet yes, i got the error, so what did on pre submit event, i get the selected dropdown value and convert it into the object and set the form field data attribute. now it did not prompts any erorr.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I wrote a bundle here to deal with "extensible" choice types (also entity or document) :
https://github.com/Alsatian67/FormBundle/blob/master/Form/Extensions/ExtensibleSubscriber.php

How I do it :

Hooking in the form submission process, we can access to the submitted entity by the PRE_SUBMIT FormEvent.
All submitted entity are loaded and are in $event->getData().

Then we have just to take this submitted choices as new 'choices' option for the field.

Caution : 
Doing it so it will only validate that the entity submitted exist !
If only a part of the entities are possible choices you have to add a constraint to validate them.

You can also set the choices in the PRE_SUBMIT event, depending on the value of the first dropdown (instead of using all submitted entities).

Comment: i have added the event, but on changing province dropdown nohting happens. See the updated questions now.

Comment: This event is only fired when you submit your form.

Comment: Write some exit(dump('foo')); in your preSubmitData method to know if it is fired.